# Convert not in to not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert this query from a `not in` to a `not exists`

```
select id, name, cat from posts where id not in (1, 100)
```

how do I turn this into a not exists

Comment: Just curious... Why do you need to do that? It seems your current query is ok.

Comment: When I use NOT IN my query takes 9 min. When I remove NOT IN it takes 13 secs. Just wanted to see if NOT exists would make a difference

Comment: As an aside: ensure `id` is indexed.

Comment: Odd that such a simple `not in` would take 9 minutes, but a total table scan would take 13 seconds.  Even `id` not being indexed wouldn't explain this.  Did you post the complete query, or is there anything else to it?  What does `EXPLAIN PLAN` say for the query with `not in`?

Comment: This is not the whole query. I have a few joins in the query but just needed to see an example of how a NOT EXISTS would look like. I do not have access to the whole database and I cannot show the whole query.

Comment: @Luke101 - How are you measuring the elapsed time for the two queries?  Are you looking at the time required to fetch the first row?  Or the time required to fetch the last row?  Is `id` the primary key?  Or are there a large number of rows with an `id` of either 1 or 100?  What is the query plan with and without the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       cat 
FROM   posts p 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   (SELECT 1 AS col 
                           FROM   dual 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT 100 AS col 
                           FROM   dual) a 
                   WHERE  p.id = a.col);
```

Your current query is good.But still if you want it using NOT EXISTS give this a try.

Comment: How is this the same? You're ignoring the `100`, you haven't aliased `col` so this won't work

Comment: Is this Oracle existentialism?  ;)

Comment: Wow..I am a newbie at oracle and my first time seeing the dual table. Looked it up on google and i learned something new today!

Comment: I have tried this query and it is not much difference at all. But this is very interesting. Now i know I have much to learn about oracle.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert this... `not exists` would be appropriate if you were using a sub-query, not a hard-coded list of values.

Your current query is good.